# Using a List<> as a model - asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

So I am returning a view with a List as a model as such:

```
List<Indications.Analysis.PrepaymentResult> resultsList = Indications.Analysis.PrepaymentResult.GetPrepaymentResult(indication.Model.Trx, indication.Model.ShockBpsDropList.Value, indication.Model.ShockIncrements.Value);
return View(@"~\Views\Indications\TermSheetViews\Swap\PrePayment.aspx", resultsList);
```

1. This compiles but, can I do this?
2. I need to work with this list in javascript, I have code on another page that gets the list in Json from AJAX but in this case I don't have the ability to do that. How would I then work with the list that I am passing in through javascript, with the following method:

   CreateShockTable(data.prepaymentList, "TotalValueString", "#valueTable", "Prepayment Value");

That `prepaymentList` is this list.

Comment: I'm trying this currently by declaring it as ViewData and then passing that back. I'll let you guys know how it works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serialize the model into a JSON object using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prepaymentList = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
    // TODO: use the list here, for example pass it to some function:
    CreateShockTable(
        prepaymentList, 
        "TotalValueString", 
        "#valueTable", 
        "Prepayment Value"
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can.

   var myList = ViewData["whatever"] as List<Indications.Analysis.PrepaymentResult>;
2. It is translated into JSON Array during serialization, so you can easily loop through it.
   I don't clearly understand what do you mean by "passing in through javascript". Is it a result of the action called through Ajax?

Comment: How would I access it though?